# Multiple Timers in ListView buttons WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been struggling with the problem of adding a Timer to a Button in Listview for some time. I have about 100 buttons in ListView. I would like everyone to measure 15 minutes to the end after clicking. So far I have written something like this but is not working:

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();            
private DateTime Timers_end;

private void Button_ListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var BTN = sender as Button;          

        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += delegate 
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            Timers_end = now.AddMinutes(15);

            BTN.Content = (Timers_end - now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); 

        };           
        timer.Start();            
    }
```

I would like each button to work independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work in this way:

```
private void Button_ListView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

    timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        var remaining = endTime - DateTime.Now;

        if (remaining < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            btn.Content = remaining.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    };

    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: The important point here was to create a new timer on each click. It should however still be a DispatcherTimer to avoid the need to explicitly call Dispatcher.Invoke(). Also note that neither the `timer` nor the `Timers_end` class members were necessary for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of DispatcherTimer for each button. You can store these instances on a Dictionary. I think the code below can make the job

```
class TimerInfo
{ 
    public DispatcherTimer timer { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timers_end { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<Button, TimerInfo> timers = new Dictionary<Button, TimerInfo>();

private void Button_ListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var BTN = (Button)sender;

    if (!timers.TryGetValue(BTN, out TimerInfo timer))
    {
        timer = new TimerInfo { timer = new DispatcherTimer() };
        timers[BTN] = timer;
    }

    timer.timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        timer.Timers_end = now.AddMinutes(15);

        BTN.Content = (timer.Timers_end - now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

    };
    timer.timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: now it should be ok

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work. The timer starts but does not count down.

Comment: @MichałSchmude It does not count down because of `timer.Timers_end = now.AddMinutes(15);`, which means that `timer.Timers_end - now` is always 15 minutes. That does of course make no sense at all.

Comment: @MichałSchmude you are right.. This line should be moved on the initialization of the TimerInfo class